# Make HTML input stretch to fill space in container

Tags: css, html, stretch

There is a `<div id="MyDiv">` element which is resized depending on page width. It contains `<input>` and `<a>` elements.

How can I make the `<a>` align by the right side of the `<div>` and the `<input>` stretch to fit the free space between `<div>`'s left side and `<a>`'s right side?

Also the `<a>` should not jump to the next line and there are also defined `min-width` and `max-width` on the container. Here is the code:

```
<div id="MyDiv" style="background:#AAAAAA; width:100%; min-width:300px; max-width:600px;">
    <input type="text" id="MyInput"/>
    <a id="MyButton" href="#">Button</a>
</div>
```

and [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aGHqV/3/).

Comment: o yea i forgot to tell you to, try not to use inline css.

Answer (score 15):

This can be done easily with CSS3 although it will not work in IE9 or below. IE10 is the first Internet Explorer version to support the standard. The other browsers [already support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) the relevant [Flexible Box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) properties.

```css
div {
  background: #AAAAAA;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 600px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}

input {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
}

a {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <a href="#">Button</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The input won't stretch on webkit engines such as Safari or mobile devices. You'll need to put it inside a block element (such as a div) or make it display:block itself to get the expected result.

Comment: Here is a link to flex documentation for the current take on this (i.e. use `display: flex`) https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to use jQuery to calculate the width.
Try this:

```
$( window ).bind("resize", function(){
    fitInput();
});
//resize on window change

$(document).ready(function(){
   fitInput(); 
});
//resize after loading

function fitInput(){
    var divW = $("#MyDiv").width();
    var buttonW = $("#MyButton").width();
    $("#MyInput").width(divW - buttonW - 10);
}
//resize function
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Burnacid/aGHqV/4/

Comment: Thank You, this is exactly what I needed. Also I'd like to know if it is even possible with html and css only?

Comment: Not that i know of. you will always be slightly off. i don't know if CSS 3 added anything for this though.

Comment: If its exactly what you needed, you should mark his answer.  I found this answer helpful also.

Comment: This may have made sense in 2013, but please don't anyone do this in this or any future decade. jQuery is not necessary for styling something to fit a window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="MyDiv" style="position:relative;background:#AAAAAA; min-width:300px; max-width:600px;padding:0px 2px">
                <input type="text" id="MyInput" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;border:0px;width:100%;"/>
                <a id="MyButton" href="#" style="position:absolute;right:0px;top:0;padding:0px 2px; background:#aaa;">Button</a>
            </div>
        <body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uPZcW/

Comment: Throw away the inline css plz. it is a nice sollution to the point where the input is filled 100%. Because you layer the button ontop of the input text drops off

Comment: "text drops off" - in any case, if the text is more than the length of the field.

Answer (score -1):

try this html :

```
<div id="MyDiv" style="background:#AAAAAA; width:100%; min-width:300px; max-width:600px;">

       <input type="text" id="MyInput" style="width:74%;float:left"/>

       <a id="MyButton" href="#"  style="width:24%;float:right">Button</a>

  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I was searching for solutions to this very problem, or at least I think it's the same issue. I solved it too. Let me explain.

Depending on the browser, I had the textbox get too long or too short, but also noticed it sometimes did fit as intended. I used `@meadia` constructs to scale the UI depending on client viewport size and noticed it fit perfectly when the scaling was 100%, only. This led me to a different solution, or rather, pointed me to a different problem.

I am not sure this is the case for all browsers, but I could solve it by adding a few simple settings in the start of my CSS file (the CSS reset part), adding the following:

```
/***************************************************/
/* Hack to make input[type='text'] fit width of
   parent element */

input {font-size: 1em;}  /* omitting [type=... deliberately */
textarea {font-size: 1em;}

/***************************************************/
/* Media scaling */

*      {margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;}
html   {min-width: 300px;}
body   {font-size:  80%;}  /* Default */
@media (min-width:  400px) {body {font-size:  80%;}}
@media (min-width:  600px) {body {font-size:  90%;}}
@media (min-width:  900px) {body {font-size:  95%;}}
@media (min-width: 1300px) {body {font-size: 100%;}}
@media (min-width: 1800px) {body {font-size: 110%;}}
@media (min-width: 2400px) {body {font-size: 120%;}}
```

Apparently using a CSS reset that specifies font size before scaling fixes the problem. I think this actually makes sense too. The thing easily forgotten is that elements are not always inheriting correctly from the body, in this case text type inputs (and also textareas).

Make sure you are setting the `width: 100%;` style for the textbox in the TD or DIV, and that you are also setting `box-sizing: border-box;`. Should make it work.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -4):

Just add this in your `<head>` tag

```
input{width:92%;}
```

Comment: If you say in `head tag`, then you should wrap input styling into `<style>`. Otherwise it will do nothing. Input has to be maximum `90%` width as link will not stay inline if more.

Comment: This is how I did this before. It works while div is maybe at least 500px wide. It should work for page width starting from 300px or even less.